# Adding field to solr dynamically

Tags: solr

My database model is designed using dynamic attributes (Entity Attribute Value model).
For the db I have a service that adds a new attribute. 
But everytime a new attributes is added I need to add it to the schema.xml

Is there a possibile way to add a field to solr schama.xml dynamically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to configure a set of `<dynamicField/>` in accordance with the dynamic attribute naming feature.

With [dynamicField](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Dynamic+Fields), you can create field rules that Solr will use to understand what datatype should be used whenever it is given a field name that is not explicitly defined, but matches a prefix or suffix used in a dynamicField.

Restriction : the glob-like pattern in the name attribute must have a "`*`" only at the start or the end.

```
<dynamicField name="fm_*" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

`name="fm_*"` will match any field starting with fm_*. Longer patterns will be matched first. If equal size patterns both match, the first appearing in the schema will be used.

By doing this, the next step is to create a rule in the attribute naming service : prepend a prefix (or append a suffix) to the attribute's name according to its type (you might want to focus on field types to make efficient mappings). In the example "fm_" corresponds to float multivalued fields.